# How to disable the settings button in android tablet 4.0

Tags: android

I'm creating an app which is required to be fullscreen. By what I mean fullscreen is that, based on the image below, the whole area where I boxed with orange should be removed. But from searching answers, there is no way that could do that. Or maybe there is? But mostly other said that 4.0's prevents this one. So, I'll just have to override the back button and home button. The third button only functions when other apps are running, so i dont have to override that since I will be running other applications. I made it as a home app as my solution to the home button problem.

My question is, how can i override the `Settings` button (or did i use the right term for this)? The one I boxed with purple.
Because I don't want the user to mess with that either. 
Maybe there are methods in which i can override with?

Any help would great. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a low profile for your system bar so that it's not so noticeable, but when it comes to tablets, you can't actually get rid of it.

From official [doc](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0.html)

> The SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE flag replaces the STATUS_BAR_HIDDEN
>   flag. When set, this flag enables “low profile" mode for the system
>   bar or navigation bar. Navigation buttons dim and other elements in
>   the system bar also hide. Enabling this is useful for creating more
>   immersive games without distraction for the system navigation buttons.
>
> The SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE flag replaces the STATUS_BAR_VISIBLE flag
>   to request the system bar or navigation bar be visible.
>
> The SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION is a new flag that requests the
>   navigation bar hide completely. Be aware that this works only for the
>   navigation bar used by some handsets **(it does not hide the system
>   bar on tablets)**. The navigation bar returns to view as soon as the
>   system receives user input. As such, this mode is useful primarily for
>   video playback or other cases in which the whole screen is needed but
>   user input is not required.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should so much better it you Use the: "GMD Hide Bar Root" directly from Play Store, I use it in an app I create and it works fantastic, the only thing you need is to be a root user and that's all, it even has a widget you can use directly from your desktop and auto start option at boot, try it out.